# How to make plot of each variable in dataframe using loop in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a large dataset with 30 different variables. I want to investigate some characteristics of each variable by making a histogram for each variable. 
For example, for my variable `A` this now looks like:

```
hist = qplot(A, data = full_data_noNO, geom="histogram", 
    binwidth = 50, fill=I("lightblue"))+
    theme_light()
```

Now, I want do this for all my variables. Does anyone know how I can loop through the names of all variables of my dataframe (so `A` should change each iteration).

Also, I want to loop through all variables in this code for the same purpose:

```
avg_price = full_data_noNO %>% 
    group_by(Month, Country) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(total = mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Take a look at [ggplot2 - create a barplot for every column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822840/ggplot2-create-a-barplot-for-every-column-of-a-dataframe). You'll find two different approaches that hopefully help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could reference your variables by column number:

```
histograms = list()
for(i in 1:ncol(full_data_noNO)){
histograms[[i]] = qplot(full_data_noNO[,i], geom="histogram", 
    binwidth = 50, fill=I("lightblue"))+
    theme_light()
}
```

Comment: Then I get the error `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (961): colour, x, y, group` when making a boxplot and using aes(). Do you maybe know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your data? I'm testing with `df = data.frame(
  x1 = rpois(100,3),
  x2 = rnorm(100,0,1),
  x3 = rexp(100,1/2))
)` and it's working fine.

Comment: Closing curly brace for the `for` loop is missing. Also, you need to output the plots in list as loop will only store them.

Comment: It now worked when I transform my data vector to a data frame. However in the following `dplyr::summarize(avg_CATALOGUE_PRICE = mean(full_data_noNO[,6], na.rm = TRUE))` it returns incorrect values which are constant for all rows which is incorrect. Any idea why?

Comment: Edited to include the braces

Answer (score 0):

If all your variables are numeric, then you can do the following to produce a list of all plots, which you can then explore one by one with list indexing:

```
library(tidyverse)
list_of_plots <-
  full_data_noNO %>%
  map(~ qplot(x = ., geom = "histogram"))
```