# Automatic creation of barplots for all columns

Tags: r, bar-chart

For a very large table, I would like to automatically have a barplot for each column, which is then also saved as a png.

The title can simply be the column title and the description of the columns correspond to the column variables. So no individual edit of the barplots is necessary

I have already created barplots by hand and experimented with the "lapply" command without success.
Here the barplot code

```
png(file="a_x.png", width=600, height=400)
barplot(table(Example$a_x), main = "a_x")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Data [as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) please. We cannot read data into R from images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 - create a barplot for every column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822840/ggplot2-create-a-barplot-for-every-column-of-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `for` loop and `paste0` for the file name:

Data

```
df <- data.frame(a_x = sample(c("Yes","No"), 100, prob = c(0.10,0.90), replace = TRUE),
                 b_x = sample(c("Yes","No"), 100, prob = c(0.10,0.90), replace = TRUE),
                 c_x = sample(c("Yes","No"), 100, prob = c(0.10,0.90), replace = TRUE))
```

Code

```
for(i in colnames(df)){
  png(file = paste0(i,".png"), width = 600, height = 400)
  barplot(table(df[i]), main = i)
  dev.off()
}
```